# How to add values matching from table B to table A?

Tags: mysql, query, table

I've been struggling for a while now. Can someone help me?

I have 2 tables.

I have a table '**SKUS_info**' with SKUS(a number assigned to a product), approximately about 30k rows.

And the second table '**truckparts_info**' with all the data about products. It has 2 million rows. **OE_NUMBER** is identical to **SKU** from the first table.
[image]

I want to fill the table SKUS_info with the data from the table truckparts_info

What I tried to do:

I wrote a script:

```
select v.sku, v.net_price t.TTC_TYP_ID, t.CAR_BRAND,t.CAR_MODEL, t.CAR_TYPE,
t.CAR_BODY, t.CAR_OF_YEAR, t.CAR_KW, t.CAR_PM, t.CAR_CC,
t.ART_NAME, t.ART_GROUP, t.PARTS_INFO, t.ART_CROSS 
from truckparts_info t inner join skus_info v on t.OE_NUMBER= v.SKU order by v.SKU
```

But it does exact opposite of what I need. The v.SKU and v.Net_price are being added to the table B and the query result shows 500k rows in the end.

Any ideas how to change the script the way I want?

EDIT:

The script output is:
[image]

In this case you can see that SKU, Net_price are added to the table B

Comment: Please remove verbal table structure definitions and add output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` commands. Then show some example data (2-3 records) for there tables and desured result on that data. *I want to fill the table SKUS_info with the data from the table truckparts_info* You need UPDATE query, not SELECT one.

Comment: Not sure I understand why you say that it does the opposite of what you need. Adding example data and outcome as @Akina asks will be helpful. Also please add a case where `thuckparts_info` has more than one row with the same `OE_NUMBER` value and clarify what you want to happen in that case.

Comment: Added additional information. The thing is that the table B has a lot of information which is duplicated.

Comment: Please check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) as to why screenshots as opposed to text are not good! Also, please post any tables and data as DDL (`CREATE TABLE blah (...);`) and DML (`INSERT INTO blah VALUES (...);`). p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Use a multi-table `UPDATE` that `JOINs` the two tables but `SETs` only the one you want to change.